# Using "Predefined character classes" on a substring

Tags: java, regex

I want to check the last character of the String for characters that are not a non-word character using '\W' and allow certain symbols like ". , ! etc" from the top of my head I thought of using a code similar to this.

```
Boolean notCompleted = true;
           int deduct = 1;
           while(notCompleted){
               if(string.charAt(string.length() -deduct) == '\W'){ // '\W' <-- doesn't work since it accepts anything other than "escape sequences".
                   if(string.charAt(string.length() -deduct) == '.'||string.charAt(string.length() -deduct) == ','||string.charAt(string.length() -deduct) == '!'){
                       //Do nothing and move on to the while loop
                   }else{
                       //Replace the non word character with ' '.
                   }
               }
               deduct++;
               if(deduct >= html.length()){
                   notCompleted = false;
               }
           }
```

The reason why this doesn't work is because using string.charAt only accepts "Escapes sequence".

> My question is there another way to pull this off rather than doing.

```
string.replaceAll("\W", "");
```

All suggestions is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Thanks to the tip npinti gave me I built this code. However I am getting an error line

Desired Result of fakeNewString as requested should be "!        asdsdefwef.,a,,sda.sd";

```
fakeNewString = sb.toString(); // NullPointerException

public static void test5(){
        Boolean notCompleted = true;
        String fakeNewString = "!@#$%^&*( asdsdefwef.,a,,sda.sd";
        int start = 0, end = 1;
           StringBuilder sb = null;
           try{

        while(notCompleted){
               start++;
               String tempString = fakeNewString.substring(start, end);
               if(Pattern.matches("\\W$", tempString)){
                   if(Pattern.matches("!", tempString)||Pattern.matches(".", tempString)||Pattern.matches(",", tempString)||Pattern.matches("\"", tempString)){
                       //do nothing
                       sb.append(tempString);
                   }else{
                       //Change it to spaces.
                       tempString = " ";
                       sb.append(tempString);
                   }
               }
               end++;
               if(end >= fakeNewString.length()){
                   notCompleted = false;
                   fakeNewString = sb.toString();
                   System.out.println(fakeNewString);
               }
           }

       }catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
           e.printStackTrace();
       }
}
```

Comment: Can you give some examples of input and expected output? e.g. `"foo!"` -> `true`, `"bar"` -> `false`

Comment: Oh this code doesn't work it's a sample of my thought process. Using substring it only accepts "Escapes sequence" such as \n, \t, etc

Comment: I updated the sample thought code with more comments.

Comment: @Akyllite, I second Matts request for example strings and desired result. Could you show us some examples?

Comment: Sure Ill add the desired results.

Comment: Desired results is added above the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `String.replaceAll` in a slightly different way to do this. It achieves the same effect as the code you're trying to write, which seems like a complex solution for a simple problem. Try this code:

```
string.replaceAll("[^\\w!,.]", " ");
```

All the invalid characters are now replaced by a space, and multiple sequential occurrences of them are replaced by multiple spaces.

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like so:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\W$");
Matcher matcher = pattern.match(string);

if (matcher.find())
{
    //do something when the string ends with a non word character
}
```

Take a look at [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/index.html) tutorial for more information on regular expressions.

Answer (score 1):

Lets try to break down the question (desire) and answer it:

> I want to check the last character of the String for characters that are not a non-word character using '\W' and allow certain symbols like ". , ! etc"

---

First we have:

> I want to check the last character of the String

Expression for character X at end of string:

```
X$
```

Then:

> for characters that are not a non-word character

Expression:

`[^\W]` i.e. `\w`

And also:

> allow certain symbols like ". , ! etc"

Added to the expression above:

```
[\w.,!]
```

---

And the combined final result is:

```
[\w.,!]$
```

*Ta-da! (Altho I'm guessing OP is looking for something else, I did it for teh lulz.)*

Comment: You sure? I wasn't expecting this to be a correct answer. :-P